# Duplicates In a String

Tags: string, hash, lua, duplicates, character

I need to write a function that takes a string and returns it with duplicate characters removed in Lua. What I need help with is...

- Making a hash with letters and the counts
- Making each letter equal to only one, deleting more than one occurrence
- Converting hash into the new string with duplicates removed

A simple function/algorithm would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need one instance of each character then you probably don't need to keep track of the counts; you can compare the input string against the same table you use to generate the output.

```
local function contains(tbl, val)
  for k,v in pairs(tbl) do 
    if v == val then return true end
  end
  return false
end

local function uniq(str)
  local out = {}
  for s in str:gmatch(".") do
    if not contains(out, s) then out[#out+1] = s end
  end
  return table.concat(out)
end

print( uniq("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog") )
-- the quickbrownfxjmpsvlazydg
```

This will probably be slower than the function below for short strings, but it's generally best to avoid excessive string concatenation in Lua, for the reasons outlined [here](http://www.lua.org/pil/11.6.html).  If you're sure the output string will be fairly short, you can get rid of `contains()` and use this:

```
local function uniq(str)
  local out = ""
  for s in str:gmatch(".") do
    if not out:find(s) then out = out .. s end
  end
  return out
end
```

Comment: I used the shorter one, it worked perfectly! Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help. Perfect solution.